# fcntl couldn't lock /dev/null and hang

Tags: files

A minimal working example, but only for my machine:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


  int fd = open ("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
  if (fd < 0) {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
  }

  struct flock lock;
  lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
  lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
  lock.l_start = 0;
  lock.l_len = 0;

  int res = fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW,&lock); // this hangs
  if (res < 0) {
    printf("Failed to lock\n");
  }
  close (fd);
  return (0);
}
```

The program above **hangs only on my machine**, and completed instantly on 7 other machines. Is there anything that I can look into to investigate this problem?

**strace** shows that fcntl was getting stuck when the program (./t) was killed by ^C.

```
5249  execve("./t", ["./t"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
5249  brk(NULL)                         = 0x1cf6000
5249  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
5249  access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
5249  open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
5249  fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=98358, ...}) = 0
5249  mmap(NULL, 98358, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f31a1118000
5249  close(3)                          = 0
5249  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
5249  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
5249  read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
5249  fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1868984, ...}) = 0
5249  mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f31a1117000
5249  mmap(NULL, 3971488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f31a0b42000
5249  mprotect(0x7f31a0d02000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
5249  mmap(0x7f31a0f02000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7f31a0f02000
5249  mmap(0x7f31a0f08000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f31a0f08000
5249  close(3)                          = 0
5249  mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f31a1116000
5249  mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f31a1115000
5249  arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f31a1116700) = 0
5249  mprotect(0x7f31a0f02000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
5249  mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
5249  mprotect(0x7f31a1131000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
5249  munmap(0x7f31a1118000, 98358)     = 0
5249  open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 03777762203636510) = 3
5249  fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=0}) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
5249  --- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
5249  +++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

Comment: First thing to look into would be `strace`.

Comment: @Jos Thanks, I added strace output, what else I can look into?

Comment: Why do you want a lock on `/dev/null`?

Comment: You are asking `fnctl` to obtain an exclusive (write) lock `l_type=F_WRLCK`, where (according to `man fnctl`) `F_SETLKW` means *"... but if a conflicting lock is held on  the  file, then  wait  for that lock to be released"*. You may be able to see why there is a conflicting lock using `lslocks` - see [How to list processes locking file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85997/65304). If you don't want `fnctl` to wait in the case of conflict, then try `F_SETLK` in place of `F_SETLKW`. Regardless, @vidarlo 's point applies - it doesn't seem like a good idea to be write-locking `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. @steeldriver's comment was very useful, it helped me to understand what was the problem.

> You are asking fnctl to obtain an exclusive (write) lock
>   `l_type=F_WRLCK`, where (according to `man fnctl`) `F_SETLKW` means "... but
>   if a conflicting lock is held on the file, then wait for that lock to
>   be released". You may be able to see why there is a conflicting lock
>   using `lslocks` - see [How to list processes locking file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85997/65304)?. If you don't
>   want `fnctl` to wait in the case of conflict, then try `F_SETLK` in place
>   of `F_SETLKW`. Regardless, @vidarlo 's point applies - it doesn't seem
>   like a good idea to be write-locking `/dev/null`.

For those who are interested in this problem, it was docker daemon that locked `/dev/null` on my machine. Some more information can be found here:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31182

As why I need to lock `/dev/null`, I have a testsuite that writes to `/dev/null` instead of writing to the network. The testsuite is for a different component, written by a different team based in a different continent. So it is not clear for me either :)